# Why can I ping client → server, but not server → client, in a Wireguard context?

Tags: vpn, wireguard

I have Wireguard set up on an Arch server (the server is both on the LAN `192.168.10.0/24` network as `192.168.10.2`, and the WG one (`192.168.20.0/24`, he is `192.168.20.0`).

I connect to this server from a client on the Internet (I will use *client* and *server* words to make it clear which peers I am talking about). The WG IP is `192.168.20.3`.

**What works**

I can connect from the client to the server → from the client all of the below are OK

- `ping 192.168.20.0` → client to WG endpoint on the server
- `ping 192.168.10.2` → client to the server LAN IP
- `ping 192.168.10.68` → client to a machine on the LAN

**What does not work**

I cannot ping the client from the server:

```
root@srv ~# ping 192.168.20.3
PING 192.168.20.3 (192.168.20.3) 56(84) bytes of data.

^C
--- 192.168.20.3 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6081ms
```

Since the client → sever connectivity is OK, it means that the routing is fine (packets can go to the devices on the LAN and come back afterward)

The routing table on the server:

```
root@srv ~ [1]# ip r
default via 192.168.10.1 dev enp3s0 proto static
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-4f4174b6b888 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
192.168.10.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.2
192.168.10.0/24 dev wg0 proto static scope link
192.168.20.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.20.0
```

On the client:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.113     45
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.113    301
    192.168.0.113  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.113    301
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.113    301
     192.168.10.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.20.3      5
   192.168.10.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.20.3    261
     192.168.20.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.20.3      5
     192.168.20.3  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.20.3    261
   192.168.20.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.20.3    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.113    301
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.113    301
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the firewall on my laptop (the "client") that drops all incoming packets (except a few services) and since this is a centrally managed service I cannot do anything to fix the connectivity.

Comment: You sure it is the firewall you did not deactivate the ping response on the client?

Comment: @BlockchainOffice: yes. My work laptop is closed down outside of the AD domain so it is normal that a packet with an external source (such as a WG client) is rejected. I found them in the firewall logs (dropped).

Comment: Ok so you found the solution for your problem?

Comment: @BlockchainOffice: well, yes - this is why I posted it as an answer.